# Finding radial and tangential velocity

Tags: kinematics, vectors, velocity

Given $$\vec r =r\cos(θ(t))\hat i  +r\sin(θ(t))\hat j $$ and $$θ(t)=t^2 $$(everything in mks). I am supposed to find the radial and tangential components of the velocity at $t = 2$ seconds. But I am not sure if I should consider this equation as if it is related to circular motion. If so, would not there be only tangential velocity, since the radial velocity is zero? Is the derivative of $\vec r$ with respect to $t$ useful in this case? Also, how is it possible to find any velocity components just by its equation?

Comment: How is the second equation dimensionally correct?

Comment: As $\theta$ changes, the magnitude of the $x$ and $y$ components of $\vec{r}$ are changing. So there is radial speed.

Comment: Changing $\theta$ just shows that angular velocity is not constant, i.e. $$\omega = d \theta/dt = 2 t$$ and that circular movement has angular acceleration $\alpha = d\omega/dt = 2~ rad/\text{s}^{-2}$. How from this you extrapolate that there is a radial speed ? It's quite in contrary,- circle equation $$ \sqrt{(r \cos(\theta))^2 + (r \sin(\theta))^2} = | \vec r | $$ shows that it's constant. I see no radial component here.

Comment: This equation on the question is not related to circular motion, it turns out. Derivative of it is radial component while there is no tangential component of this velocity. As you try to draw the motion, it just goes back and front repeatedly. And passes through origin on coordinate plane, therefore there is only radial velocity. At least that is what I have understood so far.